# SQL Aggregation and Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Just diving into SQL and had seen a report format that I like and was hope this is the right forum to ask. i am familiar with basic select statements and grouping but I am stumped on how to do this or if it is possible with a single data table.

Anyways below is a sample of a table I have.

    Table:

```
Item      Loc   Frozen     Scanned    Adj
1457481   85      0         1          1
1457481   85      0         1          1
1457481   25      1         1          0
1457481   25      1         1          0
1457481   35      1         1          0
1457481   45      1         1          0

Here is the format I would like to show:

Item       GoodLoc     Adj
1457481     2@25       2@85
            1@35
            1@45
```

Is this even possible without joining additional tables? Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Yes, this is possible, though your format is unconventional for displaying results. Essentially, first you just need to SUM your frozen/adj columns, grouping by your item and loc columns. This will give you a basic result set to work with. To get your specific formatting requires a little weirdness with row numbers and a self-join.

Comment: SQL doesn't work well as a presentation layer.  Use SQL to grab the data (do sums/aggregation/joins), use another language to display them however you would like.

Comment: Thank you. Was just a general question if it was possible. I am dabling in in SSRS as well and that seems to be the way to go. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more details of the problem this is just guesswork but here is a possible solution:

Assuming table:

```
CREATE TABLE Items
(
    item    INT,
    Loc     INT,
    Frozen  BIT,
    Scanner BIT,
    Adj     BIT
)
```

try

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        Item,
        CASE
            WHEN Frozen = 0
            THEN NULL
            ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),COUNT(Loc) OVER (PARTITION BY Loc)) + '@' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Loc)
        END As GoodLoc,
        CASE
            WHEN Adj = 0
            THEN NULL
            ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),COUNT(Adj) OVER (PARTITION BY Adj)) + '@' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Loc)
        END As Adj
FROM    Items
ORDER BY GoodLoc DESC
```

As others have said, it seems like you are trying to present data which you should do in the presentation layer (SSRS) rather than Management Studio

Comment: Thanks. Was just curious if it was possible. Appreciate the code and will keep it noted should I need it as a reference. Greatly appreciate it.